# Dead Island from Steam not working on my ubuntu 17.10

Tags: games

I have an hp pavilion notebook with ubuntu 17.10, when I was using windows, I could run dead island. 
Under linux on the same machine the game crashes at the first wait screen. 
If for example I run the game with launch options -nologos -safemode 
I get the Palm screen, the black screen with wait message and then the game just crash. 
I also noticed that the game does not make any configuration file since the folder settings: /DI/out/Settings/ doesn't exist. 
I double checked the integrity of game files.
I can provide also the crash.log file (very long log file) since I can't figue out the issue by myself.

To fix a glx issue I had in dota 2 I had to sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
dota 2 works fine, dead island isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

use mesa at version 18 at least.

for example from here:

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

the game works